# Django NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Tags: django

I have imported these modules:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
```

and then I try to call a class like so:

```
sh = MyClass(request.FILES['img'])
sh.read_image()
```

but it throws error "NameError: name 'request' is not defined", but I don't get it why, because I have imported necessary modules.

Answer (score 5):

Where are you making your class? If you want access to a `request`, you usually have to be inside a view, like so:

```
def my_view(request):
    sh = MyClass(request.FILES['img'])
    sh.read_image()
    return render_to_response('template.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those import statements use the name 'request', so you can't be importing that name.

In any case, the request isn't something you import, it's something that's passed to each view. If your code is outside the view, you need to pass the request to it.